# Can't get Braintree Error Messages to show in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, braintree

On my site, a user registers and gives their credit card information in the same form.  The form uses Devise to save the user.  I needed to import the actual devise code into the controller (a bad practice, i know, but with Braintree I couldn't see any other way to wrap the user and charge into one transaction).  I finally got the whole thing to work except I am having trouble with Braintree error messages.  I just tried creating a transaction with an amount of $2600 which should trigger a Braintree error and display a message, but no such error was triggered.  Here is my code:

```
def create
  nonce_from_the_client = params[:payment_method_nonce]
  # code taken from devise
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  begin
    @charge = resource.charges.build
    @charge.nonce = nonce_from_the_client
    braintree_call = nil
    @braintree_errors = nil
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
      puts "beforer resource saved".green
      resource.save!
      puts "resource saved".green

      puts "charge built".green
      puts "before call_braintree".green
      braintree_call = @charge.call_braintree!
      if braintree_call.success? && !braintree_call.errors.any?
        puts "braintree_call was a success".green

        @charge.save
        #do nothing.  All good
      else
        puts "braintree error".red
        @braintree_errors = braintree_call.errors
        braintree_call.errors.each do |error|
          puts "#{error.code}\n".red
          puts "#{error.message}".red
        end
        raise "@Charge Failed"
      end
    end
  rescue 
    puts "@charge #{@charge.inspect}".red
    puts "@charge errors: #{@charge.errors.inspect}".red
  end

  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.persisted?
    puts "resource persisted".green
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      flash[:success] = "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
      # set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      puts "not sure about this".blue
      # set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
      flash[:danger] = "signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    puts "resource did not persist".red
    clean_up_passwords resource
    set_minimum_password_length
    # respond_with resource
    puts "NOW WE KNOW".on_red
    render 'new' #not sure if this works
  end
  puts "resource errors are #{resource.errors.inspect}".red
end
```

And here is the model for Charge that includes the call_braintree method above:

```
class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user


  attr_accessor :nonce

  after_create :activate_user_account

  def activate_user_account
    puts "in the activate user account after_Create method".green
    self.user.activate
  end

  def set_amount
    amount = self.user.plan.amount * self.user.plan.length
    puts "amount is #{amount} and is class #{amount.class}".green
    return amount
  end


  def call_braintree!
    puts "in call braintree".green
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      :amount => "#{self.set_amount}",
      :payment_method_nonce => self.nonce,
      :options => {
        :submit_for_settlement => true
      }
    )
  end

end
```

Here are the server logs this generates:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-26 15:06:29 -0500
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z0jHeFqXJk6iEwdEohilVd2Io85NKoPuzUepjfSXxU0=", "user"=>{"type"=>"Presenter", "plan_id"=>"2", "organization_name"=>"", "first_name"=>"David", "last_name"=>"Applebau,", "email"=>"asfdjhfasdlk@dffadsdf.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "telephone"=>"6462343800", "group_code"=>""}, "field-fnames"=>"", "field-lnames"=>"", "payment_method_nonce"=>"815abd1c-0be5-40e4-8135-a468021c8b75"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
beforer resource saved
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'asfdjhfasdlk@dffadsdf.com' LIMIT 1
  Plan Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "organization_name", "plan_id", "plan_length", "plan_start_date", "plan_status", "telephone", "type", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2016-02-26 20:06:29.294712"], ["email", "asfdjhfasdlk@dffadsdf.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$jeIa3c.i73f/hBV7ne/Dfu0MAawQzoNak808zLqjjkFeJKmXt78yK"], ["first_name", "David"], ["last_name", "Applebau,"], ["organization_name", ""], ["plan_id", 2], ["plan_length", 1], ["plan_start_date", "2016-02-26 20:06:29.289691"], ["plan_status", "active"], ["telephone", "6462343800"], ["type", "Presenter"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-26 20:06:29.294712"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "charges" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2016-02-26 20:06:29.307071"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-26 20:06:29.307071"], ["user_id", 20]]
in the activate user account after_Create method
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 20]]
in the after method of the state machine
  Plan Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "plan_start_date" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Presenter') AND "users"."id" = 20  [["plan_start_date", "2016-02-26 20:06:29.310158"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-26 20:06:29.311003"]]
resource saved
charge built
before call_braintree
in call braintree
braintree error
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ichabod is yolo
@charge #<Charge id: nil, user_id: 20, stripe_id: nil, created_at: "2016-02-26 20:06:29", updated_at: "2016-02-26 20:06:29">
@charge errors: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ffac3f16790 @base=#<Charge id: nil, user_id: 20, stripe_id: nil, created_at: "2016-02-26 20:06:29", updated_at: "2016-02-26 20:06:29">, @messages={}>
resource did not persist
NOW WE KNOW
  Rendered layouts/logged_in/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
@type is Presenter
@free_trial is 
in here
  Plan Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."user_type" = 'Presenter' AND ("plans"."name" != 'free_trial')  ORDER BY "plans"."display_order_number" ASC
  Rendered layouts/logged_in/_registration_form_header.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/logged_in/_payment_form.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/logged_in/_registration_submit_button.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered charges/_braintree_js.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/logged_in (8.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/logged_in/_navbar.html.erb (0.4ms)
resource errors are #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ffac3fd6ae0 @base=#<Presenter id: nil, email: "asfdjhfasdlk@dffadsdf.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$jeIa3c.i73f/hBV7ne/Dfu0MAawQzoNak808zLqjjkF...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2016-02-26 20:06:29", updated_at: "2016-02-26 20:06:29", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, organization_id: nil, type: "Presenter", organization_name: "", organization_code: nil, identifier: nil, stripe_customer_id: nil, plan_id: 2, presenter_maximum: nil, workshop_id: nil, presentation_allowance: 2, plan_status: "active", plan_start_date: "2016-02-26 20:06:29", plan_length: 1, contact_name: nil, contact_phone: nil, first_name: "david", last_name: "applebaum", telephone: "6462343800", group_id: nil>, @messages={:plan_id=>[], :organization_name=>[], :first_name=>[], :last_name=>[], :email=>[], :password=>[], :password_confirmation=>[], :telephone=>[], :group_code=>[]}>
Completed 200 OK in 2171ms (Views: 81.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

The only thing I did differently in order to get a braintree error was switch the amount in the call_braintree method with 2600.

As you can see in the logs, some type of error was thrown or the call was not a success, and yet Braintree did not provide an error.  Whenever the users card does not work, for whatever reason, I need an error message from braintree to show the user.  How do I get braintree errors to properly display?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

Errors are only populated for Braintree validation errors. Processor errors are reported in the Transaction's `processor_response_code`

Appropriate error handling for Transactions that fail at the processor level would look like this:

```
if braintree_call.success? && !braintree_call.errors.any?
  puts "braintree_call was a success".green

  @charge.save
  #do nothing.  All good
elsif braintree_call.transaction
  puts "Transaction processing error: #{braintree_call.transaction.status}: Response Code: #{braintree_call.transaction.processor_response_code}\n".red
  raise "@Charge Failed"
else
  puts "braintree error".red
    @braintree_errors = braintree_call.errors
    braintree_call.errors.each do |error|
      puts "#{error.code}\n".red
      puts "#{error.message}".red
    end
    raise "@Charge Failed"
  end
```

Check out our docs for more info on [transaction statuses](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/statuses#transaction) and [processor response codes](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/processor-responses/authorization-responses)